# specify linux kernel module dependency when using jprobe

Tags: linux, module, dependencies, kernel, jprobe

I am building two linux kernel modules.

The second module (called `debugging` module hereafter) basically uses `jprobe` to intercept calling of functions inside the first module (called `main` module) and prints some states for debugging. They work pretty well. But I got one question on dependency for the `debugging` module on the `main` module.

Apparently, the `debugging` module depends on the `main` module, as when loading the `debugging` module without the `main` module loaded, I got error

```
"Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter"
```

However, it looks like that modules.dep could not figure it out. By looking at

```
nm -u <debugging_module.ko>
```

I did not find any unresolved symbol related to the `main` module. But `jprobe` needs function name from `main` module to intercept, and that is as string assigned for `.kp.symbol_name` in `jprobe` structure.

How can we specify dependency in this situation?